# How to resolve the error 'nexpected element (uri:"", local:"Create"). Expected elements are <{}Create>'?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a problem with my JAXB:

```
<element name="create">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

My XML:

```
<Create>
<name> coco </name>
</Create>
```

My Java:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("MyPackage");
 Unmarshaller decodeur =    context.createUnmarshaller();
System.out.println("text : " + message);
msgObject = decodeur.unmarshal(sr);  
     if (msgObject instanceof Create)

{
      System.out.println(" action");
}
```

And I have this:

> unexpected element (uri:"", local:"Create"). Expected elements are <{http://www.example.org/XSD_Maths}create>

And my code stopped at this line:

```
 msgObject = decodeur.unmarshal(sr);
```

Is my XML OK or is there a problem with it? I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Your XML has "Create" with uppercase "C" and your schema has "create" with a lowercase "c". Typo in your question, or typo in the code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your XML Schema probably has a `schema` tag like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/XSD_Maths" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/XSD_Maths" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```

Since it specifies a `targetNamespace` of `http://www.example.org/XSD_Maths`.  Your XML will need to look like the following:

```
<create xmlns="http://www.example.org/XSD_Maths">
    <name> coco </name>
</create>
```

### Note About Unmarshalling from a DOM

If you unmarshalling from a DOM `Document` or `Element` make sure that the DOM parser you used was namespace aware.  This is done by setting the following flag on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

```
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

### For More Information

Below is a link to an article on my blog where I go into more depth about JAXB and namespaces.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Tahnks Blaise , I have the same schema but your xml is not working

Comment: @user3557873 - Do you get a different exception?

Comment: @user3557873 - What type of object is your `sr` variable holding onto.

Comment: Thanks  so muuccccch  Blaise , I retstart my Eclipse and it's working with your xml.  Blaise you're great :)  thanks thanks

Comment: @bdoughan I have a similar problem. Can you have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67975111/xmlstreamexception-xmlns-has-been-already-bound-to-rebinding-it-to-http-deu